# ensuring at least a certain dimensionality in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function in my toolkit and heavily rely on it.  I find it hard to believe that there wouldn't be a numpy builtin that does this, but my search for likely function names in numpy, and google searches for various paraphrases of this question, has not turned up anything.  Is there something?

```
def project(a, maxdim):
    """
    Return a view of the numpy array <a> that has at least <maxdim>+1
    dimensions (pad a.shape with 1's on the right if necessary).
    """
    if isinstance(a, numpy.matrix) and maxdim > 1: a = numpy.asarray(a)
    else: a = a.view()
    a.shape += (1,) * (maxdim-len(a.shape)+1)
    return a
```

Comment: I do not see the point of your if statement; a call to numpy.asarray would accomplish the same thing. That leaves a rather simple one-liner, and no, I don't think it gets simpler than that.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn two lines: one to create a copy, one to extend shape. Anything that's more than 1 line is worth making a function for.

Comment: np.asarray(a).reshape(* (shape+(1,)*(maxdim+1-a.ndim)))
Arguably, still worth making a function for though.

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB, with default Fortran order, automatically adds dimensions on the right.  `numpy` is default C order, and prefers to append them on the left.

`np.array` takes a `ndmin` parameter, that prepends 1s as need.

e.g.

```
In [89]: np.array([1,2,3],ndmin=4).shape
Out[89]: (1, 1, 1, 3)
```

There are 3 `np.atleast_?d` functions.

```
In [92]: np.atleast_2d([1,2,3]).shape
Out[92]: (1, 3)
In [93]: np.atleast_3d([1,2,3]).shape
Out[93]: (1, 3, 1)
```

`atleast_3d` is used in `np.dstack`, and may have been written expressly for that use.

When broadcasting, `numpy` will prepend dimensions as needed; post pending them requires explicit action on your part.  That's just the default `numpy` developers chose.

```
np.ones((3,4,5))+np.zeros((5))
```

---

`np.array` takes a `copy` parameter as well

```
In [113]: x=np.array([1,2,3])
In [114]: y=np.array(x, ndmin=3,copy=False)

In [117]: y.__array_interface__['data']
Out[117]: (152332976, False)
In [118]: x.__array_interface__['data']
Out[118]: (152332976, False)
```

Comment: Good to know! Except (1) it would be nice to append, not prepend, (2) it requires allocation of a new array. Neither `asarray` nor `view` appears to support `ndmin`.

Comment: You can use `copy=False` with `np.array`.