# Is there any logic where numpy atleast_#d inserts new dimensions if necessary?

Tags: numpy

I would like to understand why numpy atleast #d doesn't always insert new dimensions (if necessary) to the specific place, say at the beginning or at the end?

The case of scalars is obviously not interesting. For 1d array `np.atleast_2d` inserts new dimension at the beginning, and np.atleast_3d inserts one dimension at the beginning and one at the end. For 2d array `np.atleast_3d` inserts new dimension at the end.

Comment: Read the code for yourself.  Those `atleast` functions were written long ago  by some developer based on what they thought would be most useful.  I don't recall much SO discussion or examples. It would be easy to write your own version if you want some other logic.  `expand_dims` is newer.  I prefer to use the `[:,None]` style to add dimensions as needed.

Comment: I don't see why (n,1,1) would be preferable to (1,n,1).  By broadcasting ru,es (n,) is just as good as (1,1,n).

Comment: `np.array` takes a `ndmin` parameter (prepending).  To a degree I think the `atleast` functions complement that.

Comment: The logic here seems to date back to 2002. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/0562713ee528cae5ac5a4386ce92d7d2c37c3b9e#diff-99bf9213b5df4ce78edbaab9065a17c7af7472a9a84f48da7b048d44e2eaf697R412 (Look in utility.py) I am not sure there is a good reason for it to be this way.

Comment: @hpaulj My question was about the logic behind such a strange implementation. I know how to add new dimensions, but the convenience of the "atleast" commands is that they are added only when necessary. (1,1,n) or (n,1,1) are preferable as they are easier to remember) According to Nick ODell's link, this implementation was done on purpose, so I guess there was some logic to it)

Comment: @NickODell Thanks! Yes, it seems like it was done intentionally, but why??

Comment: I dunno. The commit message is not enlightening. You could always try emailing the person who wrote the commit, Travis Oliphant, and asking him. Assuming he remembers after 20 years. :)

Comment: There's a consistent use of dimension `N` in `For example, a 1-D array of shape (N,) becomes a view of shape (1, N, 1), and a 2-D array of shape (M, N) becomes a view of shape (M, N, 1)`.  `atleast_3d(atleast_2d([1,2,3]))` produces the same (1,3,1).

Comment: `hstack`, `vstack`, `dstack` follow roughly the same logic.  scalars to 1d, 1d's joined on a new leading dim, 2d's joined on a new trailing dim. `dstack` uses `atleast_3d`. dito for `hstack` and `vstack`.

Comment: 8 years ago I speculated that `atleast_3d` may have be written with `dstack` in mind.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402228/ensuring-at-least-a-certain-dimensionality-in-a-numpy-array#34402367

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you, that's probably a reason!